Fourier transform of the product between a periodic and a non-periodic function
I have a function $\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\text{supp}(\widehat{\varphi}) \subset [0,1]$ and a Fourier series $R(x):=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a_k e^{ikx}$ which convergences unconditionally in the $L^2([-\pi,\pi))$-norm. How can i show that the Fourier coefficients of the product $f:=R\cdot \varphi$ are given by
\begin{align*}
\hat{f}(\xi) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_k \widehat{\varphi}(\xi-k),
\end{align*}
pointwise at least almost everywhere. A paper I am reading is using this fact. I have tried approximating $\varphi$ with Schwartz functions but I cannot exchange the sum and the integral. Also I don't think there is a version of the convolution theorem that could help. Do I need more restrictions maybe? Any help would be appreciated.

Have you explored the analytic limit representation
$$\hat{R}(\xi)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a_k, \delta\left(\xi-\frac{k}{2 \pi}\right)=\lim\limits_{f\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a_k, 2 f, \text{sinc}\left(2 \pi f \left(\xi-\frac{k}{2 \pi}\right)\right)\right)$$
which is based on the Fourier transform
$$\mathcal{F}t\lefte^{i k t}\right=\lim\limits{f\to\infty}\left(\int_{-f}^{f} e^{i k t}, e^{-2 \pi i \xi t} , dt\right)=\lim\limits_{f\to\infty}\left(2 f, \text{sinc}\left(2 \pi f \left(\xi-\frac{k}{2 \pi}\right)\right)\right)$$
of $e^{i k t}$?

thank you for the awnser. Could you elaborate on what kind of Fourier tansform that is? I am a bit confused since I haven't seen that yet and the function e^(ikt) is not lebesgue-integrable over the real line, so the classical Fourier transform doesn't apply here right?

The Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms can generally be defined as
$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}tf(t)=\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2 \pi)^{1-a}}} \int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t), e^{i b \omega t} , dt$$
and
$$f(t)=\mathcal{F}{\omega}^{-1}\hat{f}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{| b|}{(2 \pi)^{a+1}}} \int{-\infty }^{\infty } \hat{f}(\omega), e^{-i b t \omega} , d\omega$$
(see formulas (15) and (16) in the Wolfram MathWorld article on Fourier Transform).

I used the Fourier parameters ${a, b}={0, -2 \pi}$ because they're consistent with the definition assumed by the Convolution Theorem, and note they're also consistent with equations (1) and (2) in the Wikipedia article on the Fourier Transform.

This answer by user reuns to one of my MSE questions provides insight into the convergence of the Fourier transform of $e^{i k t}$ in the sense of distributions. The answer assumes the Fourier parameters ${a,b}={1, -1}$ and addresses the Fourier transform of $f(t)=1$, but the Fourier transform of $f(t)=e^{i k t}$ is related via the frequency shifting property $$f(t), e^{i k t}\stackrel{\mathcal{F}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\hat{f}(\xi-\frac{k}{2\pi})$$ of the Fourier transform.

Also, note $$f(t)=\varphi(t) \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_k, e^{i k t}$$ and $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a(k), \hat{\varphi}\left(\xi-\frac{k}{2 \pi}\right)$$ from formula (6) in my answer below are term-wise consistent with respect to the frequency shifting property $$\varphi(t), e^{i k t}\stackrel{\mathcal{F}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\hat{\varphi}(\xi-\frac{k}{2\pi})$$ of the Fourier transform.

wouldn't formula (6) be in the distributional sense and not pointwise? or am i missing something?

I attempted to respond to your last question above in comments I accidentally posted following my answer below, but perhaps a more complete answer relevant to your specific question here depends on your specific definition of $\varphi(t)$. What is your specific definition of $\varphi(t)$?

This may not be a complete answer, but illustrates an approach based on the convolution theorem.

The Fourier transform of $e^{i k t}$ is
$$\mathcal{F}_t\left[e^{i k t}\right](\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i k t}\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega t} \, dt=\delta\left(\omega-\frac{k}{2 \pi}\right)\tag{1}$$
so the term-wise Fourier transform of
$$R(t)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a_k\, e^{i k t}\tag{2}.$$
is
$$\hat{R}(\omega)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a_k\, \delta\left(\omega-\frac{k}{2 \pi}\right)\tag{3}.$$

Assuming $f(t)$ is the product
$$f(t)=R(t)\, \varphi(t)\tag{4}$$
then the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is the frequency-domain convolution
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=[\hat{R}(\omega) * \hat{\varphi}(\omega)](\xi)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{R}(\omega)\, \hat{\varphi}(\xi-\omega) \, d\omega\tag{5}$$
and term-wise evaluation based on formula (3) above leads to
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a(k)\, \hat{\phi}\left(\xi-\frac{k}{2 \pi}\right)\tag{6}$$

My interpretation of the answer by user reuns is
$$g_f(\xi)=\lim\limits_{f\to\infty} \left(\int\limits_{-f}^f e^{-2 \pi i \xi t} , dt\right)=\lim\limits_{f\to\infty} \left(2 f, \text{sinc}(2 \pi f \xi)\right)\tag{1}$$
converges to $\delta(\xi)$ in a distributional sense because the integral
$$\lim\limits_{f\to\infty} \left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g_f(\xi), \varphi(\xi) , d\xi\right)\tag{2}$$
converges to $\varphi(0)$ as $f\to\infty$ "for any $\varphi\in C^\infty_c$ (more generally for any $\varphi\in L^1, \varphi' \in L^1$)".

In other words, my interpretation is formula (1) above converges to $\delta(x)$ in a distributional sense because it produces the correct result when integrated as in formula (2) above. In a comment on another one of my MSE questions, user reuns told me the definition of $g_n(x)\to\delta(x)$ is
$$\forall \varphi(x)\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g_n(x), \varphi(x) , dx\to\varphi(0)\tag{3}.$$
But the situation here is more complicated because its an infinite series of Dirac delta functions versus a single Dirac delta function.
